# Creating dummy variable in Scilab

Tags: sparse-matrix, scilab, dummy-variable

I need to do the following:

```
A = [1,2,3; 0,4,0; 0,5,6]
B = krone (A, A)
C = sparse (dummy (B))
```

Could anyone tell me how to create a dummy variable in Scilab. I am looking for a command equivalent to the dummy var in Matlab.

Comment: Are you looking for a Scilab equivalent of Matlab's [dummyvar](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/dummyvar.html)?

Comment: Yes! I am wanting a command equivalent to the dummy var Matlab to Scilab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in Scilab version of `dummyvar` command in Matlab, but here is a function that does the same for numerical data.

```
function D = dummyvar(B)
    m = size(B, 1)
    D = zeros(m, 0)
    for j = 1:size(B, 2)
        E = zeros(m, max(B(:, j)))
        for i = 1:m
            E(i, B(i, j)) = 1
        end
        D = [D, E] 
    end
endfunction
```

Example of usage:

```
B = [1 2 1; 3 1 2; 1 2 2]
dummyvar(B)
```

Output:

```
1.    0.    0.    0.    1.    1.    0.  
0.    0.    1.    1.    0.    0.    1.  
1.    0.    0.    0.    1.    0.    1.
```

This output is the same as `dummyvar`  in Matlab returns.

Quoting the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/dummyvar.html):

> If group is a numeric vector or matrix, values in any column must be positive integers in the range from 1 to the number of levels for the corresponding variable

This is the only kind of data that my function supports; it does not deal with the categorical data. I'll point out that the code sample you gave would throw an error in Matlab too, because the matrix is numerical and contains zeros.

Comment: Right. But I think the column with only zeros should not exist, because the command is considering two in the first column. See Example for Matlab. ([Example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/dummyvar.html)

Comment: `dummyvar` in Matlab requires _all_ values in the matrix to be positive integers, if the matrix is numerical. Even one zero in a column will result in an error.